# Enabling both OCI8 and ldap in php 5.5.0 (Solaris 10) / How to add OCI8 dynamically

Tags: php, makefile, ldap, solaris, instantclient

Using the following configure statement:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/a2r/www/PHP-5.5.0 --with-apxs2=/home/a2r/apache/bin/apxs --enable-ftp --with-curl --with-zlib --with-gd --with-ldap --with-mm --with-pgsql --with-jpeg-dir=/home/a2r/www --with-png-dir=/home/a2r/www  --with-imap=/home/a2r/www/imap-2007f --with-imap-ssl --with-oci8=instantclient,/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient --enable-opcache=no
```

./configure runs successfully, however when I run make I get the following error:

```
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:96:1: warning: "LBER_ERROR" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:53:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:97:1: warning: "LBER_DEFAULT" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:54:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:100:1: warning: "LBER_BOOLEAN" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:72:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:101:1: warning: "LBER_INTEGER" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:73:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:102:1: warning: "LBER_BITSTRING" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:74:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:103:1: warning: "LBER_OCTETSTRING" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:75:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:104:1: warning: "LBER_NULL" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:76:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:105:1: warning: "LBER_ENUMERATED" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:77:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:106:1: warning: "LBER_SEQUENCE" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:78:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:107:1: warning: "LBER_SET" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:79:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:145:1: warning: "NULLBER" redefined
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:27,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:
/usr/include/lber.h:96:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/php_ldap.h:30,
             from /home/a2r/www/php-5.5.0/ext/ldap/ldap.c:45:

/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:191: error: redefinition of `struct berval'
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:1011: error: conflicting types for 'ber_init'
/usr/include/lber.h:174: error: previous declaration of 'ber_init' was here
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:1011: error: conflicting types for 'ber_init'
/usr/include/lber.h:174: error: previous declaration of 'ber_init' was here
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:1012: error: conflicting types for 'ber_peek_tag'
/usr/include/lber.h:150: error: previous declaration of 'ber_peek_tag' was here
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:1012: error: conflicting types for 'ber_peek_tag'
/usr/include/lber.h:150: error: previous declaration of 'ber_peek_tag' was here
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:1013: error: conflicting types for 'ber_skip_tag'
/usr/include/lber.h:148: error: previous declaration of 'ber_skip_tag' was here
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:1013: error: conflicting types for 'ber_skip_tag'
/usr/include/lber.h:148: error: previous declaration of 'ber_skip_tag' was here
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:1014: error: conflicting types for 'ber_scanf'
/usr/include/lber.h:168: error: previous declaration of 'ber_scanf' was here
/home/a2r/www/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include/ldap.h:1014: error: conflicting types for 'ber_scanf'
/usr/include/lber.h:168: error: previous declaration of 'ber_scanf' was here
make: *** [ext/ldap/ldap.lo] Error 1
```

If I remove the instantclient parts (last 2) from the configure command, ./configure, make, and make install seem to run correctly.

From the research I've done on this, it looks like it's a known 'issue' that ldap and OCI8 don't play well together:  https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2368820

If this is my issue, which it would appear to be, how do I go about running configure without oci8 and later adding it as a dynamic .so module?  Currently, it doesn't appear that a php.ini file even exists.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed the best solution for this was to configure the oci8 module dynamically.  To do this, I had to copy the php.ini-development file:

```
cp php.ini-development /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

Then, I added the following line to php.ini in order to dynamically run oci8:

```
Extension=oci8.so
```

The PHP / Apache guide was also a helpful resource:  http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php